# How to interact with element not highlighted in the non instrumented mode

Tags: javascript, android, automation, webdriver-io, seetest

I am in dire need of help as we have to do all mobile app automation in the non instrumented mode. For reference, we use JavaScript and WebdriverIO.

My scenario is:

Radio button 1

Radio button 2

Radio button 3

This radio button 3, I am not able to click in the Android app. It just won’t put the yellow highlight around that button or anywhere close to it in the automation dev tools in SeeTest. It works in the iOS app but in Android the yellow highlight is around all radio buttons. Though I can see each button element in the hierarchy and get the xpath from the hierarchy for Radio button 3.

I don’t know what else to do as I have never come across this before. Is there any method or workaround that you guys have used?

Thanks in advance.

I tried click, clickusingexecutor, Seetest driver execute. Since there is no yellow highlight, there is no click happening on that button.

Edit: I figured it out. I used click element using coordinates. Got the coordinates from the pointer location from Android dev tools settings

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.